# Playframework 2.5, act as a man in the middle server

Tags: java, playframework

I want my JAVA play server to act as a man in the middle server, so that requests sent in are them forwarded to another, different server. Responses from this server are sent back to the initial requester.

I imagine this is a pretty standard user care, but I cannot find any code for Play 2.5 that does this. There is some other similar question around here, sadly it is for an older version of Play.

I would also like to be able to log all incoming /outgoing requests. All requests are http://

All communications are over rest (or are just plain Gets). I'm not familiar with play framework and its CompletionStage stuff. Can i Please have some code that at least begins to put me in the right direction, I'm not looking for 10,000 mile high architecture stuff

:)

(Ideally answers will also cover scala, just because that is more comprehensive.)

Comment: You just make an http request to the other server and wait for the results and parse them. Unless you want to use RPC

Comment: i have no idea how to do that, do you have code for this?

Comment: Pretty generic question, for the middleman just lookup consuming Restful services in scala. Then for the server that does the processing, look up a restful framework for whatever language you choose for that server

Comment: I suggest you call this a "proxy server". A "man in the middle" in the context of servers only has negative connotations, of a "man in the middle attack".

Answer (score 0):

I recommend having both servers communicate over rest. So the middle man server calls the processing server via rest. However there are other options like soap and RPC

Comment: do you have even basic code that does this? or a fraction of it?